# xpath: how to select multiple tag types in a following or preceding siblings?

Tags: html, xpath, xpath-2.0, domxpath

for example, you want to select all heading tags no matter in h1, or h2, or h3, or others for following-sibling.

What do you do?

Tried:

> .//following-sibling::h*
>
> .//following-sibling::[h3|h4]
>
> .//following-sibling::(h3|h4)
>
> .//(following-sibling::h3|following-sibling::h4)

None of them working....

**updates:**

Here is my html trying to search:

```
<h3 class='title'>title1</h3>
<p> paragraph 1<p>
<p> paragraph 2<p>
<p> paragraph 3<p>
<h3 class='title'>title1</h3>
<p> paragraph 1<p>
<p> paragraph 2<p>
<h4 class='title'>title1</h4>
<p> paragraph 1<p>
<p> paragraph 2<p>
<p> paragraph 3<p>
<p> paragraph 4<p>
<h2 class='title'>title1</h2>
<p> paragraph 1<p>
<p> paragraph 2<p>
<p> paragraph 3<p>
```

so there might be randomly 2-5 paragraph between each heading, and the heading can be h2, h3, or h4.

Given a heading element, collect all the paragraphs until the next heading.

(My approach was to find the next heading and going back to find all paragraphs.)

Comment: post an XML example and result u want to get.
You solution may not be good at all.

Comment: Your question isn't clear!! What do you mean by _for following-sibling_??

Comment: Using `following-sibling` after `.//` is very strange. It's not an error, but it's a very odd thing to do. It basically selects every descendant-or-self node that isn't the first child of its parent.

Answer (score 3):

I would generally use

```
following-sibling::*[self::h3|self::h4]
```

Use of the self axis is generally preferable to testing `name()` because it avoids namespace complications, and it's probably easier for a processor to optimize.

Comment: how can we get only the 1st h3 following-sibling p's text? can anyone help me out

Answer (score 0):

I struggle so much on this problem, hence want to post this question and answer to help others.

Answer:
**

> .//following-sibling::node()[name()="h3" or name()="h4"]

**

You are welcome.

Comment: Beware of namespace effects when using `[name()='x']`. It's generally better to write `following-sibling::*[self::h3|self::h4]`

Comment: Thanks for this warning. Your tip worked, much better than mine, kudos to you! Please make an answer(not a comment), so we can vote it up. thanks.